# Is it possible to set value for TestNG annotation "enabled" attribute from a class variable?

Tags: selenium, testng

I have defined a variable enabled_status as my class variable and want to set it's value for enabled annotation of TestNG as shown below.

```
public class Test{
    boolean enabled_status = false;
    @Test(priority=1, enabled=enabled_status)
    public void testMethodA() throws InterruptedException{      
        ....code...
        ....code...
    }
```

I am getting below error message

> The value for annotation attribute Test.enabled must be a constant
>   expression

Please suggest me how I can achieve the expected behavior so that I can set value for enabled attribute from class variable or from excel.

Answer (score 0):

Annotation values cannot be set via variables. Java language doesn't allow you to do that.

If you would like to flip annotation values at runtime, then you should do the following.

1. Create an implementation of the TestNG interface `org.testng.IAnnotationTransformer`
2. Now within the `transform()` method, you would get access to the annotation as well as either the constructor or the method or the class [ Since TestNG annotations can be used on top of any of these ] and you can flip the annotation values.
3. Now you can refer to this implementation (which we call as a TestNG listener) in your `testng.xml` via the `<listeners>` tag.